# Quo and embraces

Tags: r, flextable

I'm writing a series of function to create Word tables in R using `flextable` where I'm passing down columns (that then get pivoted into `rows`) as arguments and using the embrace syntax.

I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand what exactly is going on why this segment of code `as.formula(glue::glue('~ {quo_name(enquo(rows))}'))` will work to create a string version of the argument `rows` while something like `"{rows}"` doesn't work. Is there a more simplified way to write the first expression that will help me understand it better?

I have been unable to create a reproducible example of the situation unfortunately but this did seem like it may have been related to the `flextable::merge_v()` and attempting to use `rows` for the `j` argument.

Edit:
For further context my function generally looks like this:

```
   dingo <- function(df,row){
    foo <- df %>% pivot_wider(years) %>% select({{rows}}}...)
    ft <- flextable(data = foo) %>% ...
    ft.1 <- merge_v(ft, j = as.formula(glue::glue('~ {quo_name(enquo(rows))}')))
return(ft.1)}
```

Comment: reformulate seems easier to me: `rows = letters;reformulate(rows)`. However, why do you want to use a formula if you already have chars? j supports colnames as vector.

Comment: This was literally the only thing I could get to work. I tried every variation of `{{rows}}`, `as_name()`... as I could think of. How should it be called if `rows` is being passed through?

Comment: `j = rows` - see https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/table-design.html#as-a-character-vector

Comment: @DavidGohel When I use that I get `object 'rows_item' not found` where `rows_item` would be the name of in the top of the function.

Comment: it means 'rows_item' is not existing in your data.frame

Comment: I know that it does exist though (first column of the data.frame in fact). I edited the question to show the general structure of my function incase it helps.

Comment: ok, sorry, with no reproducible example, I can't help.